# Failed Android tests - Firebase Test Lab

Tags: automated-tests, android-testing, firebase-test-lab

I'm running Android tests on Firebase Test Lab for the HUAWEI P8 Lite device (hwALE-H) and I find that a lot of tests fail, compared to other (newer) devices. The most frequent errors are:`No views in hierarchy found matching: Child at position 0 in parent with class name: is "android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupBackgroundView"`
In other devices, this error does not occur.

- Someone here with experience in this type of tests for this device?
- Can anyone tell me why there are more tests failing on this device?
- By the way, if someone can answer me, what are the characteristics of the Android devices that make them more stable in terms of Firebase tests?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not an issue with Firebase Test Lab. Devices have varying levels of performance. It may be you have a race condition in your test and you should check the Espresso documentation for how to resolve this kind of issue (assuming you are using Espresso).